# ¿Cómo puedo llamar a una función desde el método prompt en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

si alguien me pudiese ayudar, agradecería muchísimo...estoy con este problema hace unos días:
Tengo una función llamada **translate** como esta, con la cual quiero traducir algunos números a una palabra, vean:

```
function translate(Num){
    switch(Num){
        case 0: document.write('primer');
        break;
        case 1: document.write('segundo');
        break;
        case 2: document.write('tercer');
        break;
        case 3: document.write('cuarto');
        break;
        case 4: document.write('quinto');
        break;
    }
}
```

Y tengo esta otra función, donde quiero que el usuário ingrese números para reunirlos en un vector. Aquí utilizo la función **translate** para traducir el **subíndice** del loop **for** de acuerdo al lugar de cada número ingresado, vean:

```
function askNums(Nums){
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < Nums.length; i++){
        var NumsVector;
        NumsVector = parseInt(prompt(' Por favor ingrese el '+translate(i)+' número: ',' '));
        Nums[i] = NumsVector;
    }
}
```

Al ejecutar este código:

```
var Nums;
Nums = new Array(5);
askNums(Nums);
```

No aparece ni primer, ni segundo, tercero, etc. que sería la ejecución de la función **translate**... He hecho algo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu caso, lo que intentas hacer con la función `translate` es que devuelva un *string* que pueda concatenarse con el *string* del `prompt`.

Para ello, `translate` no debe hacer un `document.write`, sinó devolver el *string*.

```
function translate(Num){
    switch(Num) {
        case 0: return 'primer';
        case 1: return 'segundo';
        case 2: return 'tercer';
        case 3: return 'cuarto';
        case 4: return 'quinto';
        default: return 'unknown';
    }
}
```

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Sirvió sí, muchísimas gracias @VRoxa!